# Error when I try to use ngx-translate in angular library

Tags: angular

I am creating an angular library and I need to use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core), so like I do in the others application in app.module I add TranslateModule.forRoot

```
import ....

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LibComponent],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate: true
    }),
  ],
  exports: [LibComponent]
})
export class LibModule {
}
```

but now when I try to build it I have this error:

> ERROR: Error during template compile of 'LibModule'
> Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'TranslateModule' was called.

How can I use it without errors?

Answer (score 1):

You should  `TranslateModule.forRoot` only in main module in all other places only `TranslateModule` if you need to change settings on lazy loaded modules you can still use `TranslateModule.forChild` read info in [docs](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#lazy-loaded-modules)

Comment: it is my main lib module

Comment: same thing if I use forChild
ERROR: Error during template compile of 'OptixLibModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'TranslateModule' was called.

An unhandled exception occurred: Error during template compile of 'OptixLibModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'TranslateModule' was called.

Comment: Well it sounds same problem but different module

Comment: @user14649759 did you solve your problem?